# localhost:8080 can't be reached when using webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, package.json

I am using webpack to bundle my project.Here is the `webpack.config.js`

```
'use strict';
require("babel-plugin-syntax-jsx")
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var cache = {};
var loaders = [
    {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.es6\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
    }
];
var extensions = [
    '.js', '.jsx', '.es6.js', '.msx'
];
module.exports = [{
    cache: cache,
    module: {
        loaders: loaders
    },
    entry: {
        main: './src/main.es6.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: extensions,
        modules: [
            __dirname,
            path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
            "node_modules"
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        })
    ]   
}];
```

And here is my scripts section in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
   "build-dev": "webpack -w -d",
   "build-prod": "webpack -p"
},
```

Now when I run `npm run build-dev` the packager starts successfully with the message that webpack is watching files.. . But when I navigate to `localhost:8080` I get the message that **The site can't be reached**

I got some solutions like using `webpack-dev-server` and explicitly telling it like `webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080` but my question is why do I need webpack-dev-server.Webpack is already watching the files and also I tried configuring devServer in webpack.config.js as

```
devServer: {
   inline: true,
   port: 8000
};
```

And this is giving error for unexpected token near `port: 8000`.
I tried other port as 8000, 3000, but nowhere the site is loading.

Comment: "why do I need webpack-dev-server"  You don't...

Comment: Webpack is watching your files to compile/bundle, but you still need a web server. Any web server will do.

Comment: You likely need to replace the `;` with a `,` at the end of your `devServer` config.

Comment: Check that "," is before and after devServer, if you're using webpack 2, the docs don't seem to say that "inline" should be there.

Comment: I have fixed the `devServer` issue but still when naviagting to `localhost:8000` I am getting like the site can't be reached

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am experiencing the same issue where webpack appears to start fine but cannot access when I navigate to localhost:8080